# python socket - [Errno 57] Socket is not connected although the response is good

Tags: java, python, sockets, serversocket

I build a simple server socket in Java and use a python client socket to communicate with it. Thought the response is good, the `connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` always faile with the error `[Errno 57] Socket is not connected`. Since the client can get the response from the server, I thought the socket is already connected. But why does it constantly saying that the socket is not connected? I am super confused. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

My Client (In Python3):

```
url = '/import_image'
headers = [
    b"PUT " + bytes(url, "UTF-8") + b" HTTP/1.0",
    b'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
    b"Content-Length: " + bytes("hello world", "UTF-8"),
    b"Connection: close",
    b""
]

for h in headers:
    connection.sendall(h)
    connection.sendall(b"\r\n")

response = HTTPResponse(connection)
response.begin()
if response.status != 200:
    raise Exception("Received HTTP response {0}: {1}".format(response.status, response.reason))
else:
    print(response.read())

try:
    # This will fail with the error: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected
    connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

My Server Socket (In Java8):

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Defs.SOCKET_SERVER_PORT); // port 8888
    try {
            while (true) {
                log.info("Waiting for connection on port " + Defs.SOCKET_SERVER_PORT);
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                log.info("Connection received. Handling request...");
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()), "UTF-8"));
                String header = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n" +
                        "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
                        "Content-Length: ";
                String output = "<html><head><title>Example</title></head><body><p>success!</p></body></html>";
                out.write(header + output.length() + "\r\n\r\n" + output);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        } finally {
            serverSocket.close();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The Python client's call to `connection.shutdown()` is likely throwing the error because the connection has already been closed by the Java server, and `shutdown()` doesn't like that.

What worked for me is to call 'connection.close()' instead of 'connection.shutdown()'. I see no error when calling close.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Shawn. That is true, the `connection.shutdown()` throws the error but how? The Java server doesn't close the ServerSocket, it still can accept connection from other clients. I mean, I can run the client script multiple times and they will receive a valid response from the server but also throw an exception when trying to make `connection.shutdown()`.

Comment: `Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();` The Java server closes this socket which is the socket for the client's connection.

Comment: I am not familiar with socket programming. Please forgive me. So the server will automatically close the socket for the client's connection? Is there any way that the server doesn't close the socket and leave the job to be done by the client?

Comment: Using S for Server and C for Client, the sequence of events is something like: S: send data, C: receive data, S: close socket (implicitly at the end of the `while` loop), C: process data, C: shutdown already-closed socket (which throws the exception).

Comment: For the server to keep the socket open, it would have to keep around the `socket` variable which currently goes out of scope at the bottom of the while loop, meaning that Java is free to garbage collect it, closing the connection.